# Implement is_destructible with Detected Idiom

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Here is my implementation of [`is_destructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible):

```
template<class T>
struct is_unknown_bound_array : std::false_type
{};
template<class T>
struct is_unknown_bound_array<T[]> : std::true_type
{};

template<typename T, typename U = std::remove_all_extents_t<T>>
using has_dtor = decltype(std::declval<U&>().~U());

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_destructible_v
    = (std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_dtor, T> or std::is_reference_v<T>)
        and not is_unknown_bound_array<T>::value
        and not std::is_function_v<T>;

template<typename T>
struct is_destructible : std::bool_constant<is_destructible_v<T>>
{};
```

[clang compiled happily and passed all libstdcxx's testsuite](https://wandbox.org/permlink/euELPkPalqjRa4SL), while [gcc failed to compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0U9s2TnjiT9PmOfk):

```
prog.cc:177:47: error: 'std::declval<int&>()' is not of type 'int&'

 177 | using has_dtor = decltype(std::declval<U&>().~U());    
     |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
prog.cc: In substitution of 'template<class T, class U> using has_dtor = decltype (declval<U&>().~ U()) [with T = int&&; U = int&&]':
```

So, gcc cannot do SFINAE on `using has_dtor = decltype(std::declval<U&>().~U());`.

Question:

1. Which compiler object to standard here?
2. What's the most elegant solution/workaround here? The ways I can think of is a little ugly

Comment: It seems that GCC tries to make sure that the the type of expression `a` in `a.~B()` is the same as `B` without instantiating the function template, https://wandbox.org/permlink/4rhdNq4w7MMSIkcR

Comment: msvc also can compile(though it doesn't support `and`, `or`, `not`) https://godbolt.org/z/b9-Ii8

Comment: icc can compile: https://godbolt.org/z/ktZB3w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC seems to be broken when handling `~T()` where `T` is a reference of scalar type.

It accepts the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WEFS5YFXTGbTog60), which is clearly buggy per [[expr.pseudo]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.pseudo#2):

```
template<typename T> using tester = decltype(int{}.~T(), char{});
tester<int&> ch;
int main() {}
```

I would use `if constexpr` to implement:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool my_is_destructible() {
    if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<T>) {
        return true;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, void>
            || std::is_function_v<T>
            || is_unknown_bound_array<T>::value ) {
        return false;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_object_v<T>) {
        return std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_dtor, T>;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5qDvQGRFrglioFHa) with GCC too.