# why does type_identity break the implementation of is_detected

Tags: c++, c++17, identity, template-meta-programming, detection-idiom

[p0887r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0887r1.pdf):

> #### 2.3 Fundamental metafunction building block
>
> There are two ubiquitous idioms for type traits:
>
> - define a public data member value with a given value
> - define a public member typedef type that names a given type
>
> It is surprising that there is a standard utility providing the former (`std::integral_constant`),
>   but no standard utility providing the latter.
>   `type_identity` is this utility. It is a fundamental building block that other metafunctions can
>   simply inherit from. For example, `remove_const` could be implemented as follows:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> struct remove_const : type_identity<T> {};
> template <typename T>
> struct remove_const<T const> : type_identity<T> {};
> ```

Its implementation is simple:

```
template<class T>
struct type_identity
{
    using type = T;
};
```

So, I try to use `type_identity` widely in my codes, including personal implementation of [Detection Idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf):

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class Default,
        class AlwaysVoid,
        template<class...>
        class Op,
        class... Args>
    struct detector : type_identity<Default>                                                           // here
    {
        using value_t = std::false_type;
    };    
    template<class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>
        : type_identity<Op<Args...>>                                                                           // here
    {
        using value_t = std::true_type;
    };    
} // namespace detail
// ......
```

It works fine everywhere until I used libcxx's testsuits for [my own implementation of  `is_destructible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456848/implement-is-destructible-with-detected-idiom), below is the failure case:

```
struct ProtectedDestructor
{
protected:
    ~ProtectedDestructor()
    {}
};
// ......
template<class T>
void
test_is_not_destructible()
{
    static_assert(!is_destructible<T>::value, "");
    // ......
}
// ......
test_is_not_destructible<ProtectedDestructor>();
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xRVgiDJEaHKZUhXF):

> prog.cc:83:47: error: '~ProtectedDestructor' is a protected member of 'ProtectedDestructor'
>
> using has_dtor = decltype(std::declval().~U());
>                                                 ^
>   prog.cc:26:19: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'has_dtor' requested here
>
> ```
>            : type_identity<Op<Args...>>
>                             ^
> ```
>
> prog.cc:45:1: note: in instantiation of template class 'detail::detector
>
> ......

It's werid that **once replace `type_identity` with trival `using type = ......`, the compiler has no error**, [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UoCvae2o65k68I7u). For other trival `has_member` check, `type_identity` works fine, [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8f3uLQoCSM8dcOJL).

So, the only problem here is, for protected dtor, `type_identity` will force struct `detail::detector` to check the validity of dtor, while `using type = something` will not.

I think the solution is simple, just remove `type_identity`, and use  `using type = something` directly, just like [Walter E. Brown's original implementation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf). But the question is:

**why does `type_idintity` break here, while trival `using type = something` not?**

Comment: This looks like a clang bug to me. [It compiles fine with GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b4szl405SCKudMo8) if you use my `is_destructible` implementation from your previous question. BTW, you should create a [MCVE] to ask a language-lawyer question, there are *too much* irrelevant code here.

Comment: particularly for questions related to type-traits and tamplate-meta-programming, please, ever explicit the exact version of the standard. C++17, in this case, I suppose.

Comment: @liliscent Sorry, didn't test on gcc and remove unnecessary codes/simplify my codes are my bad.

Comment: @max66 on stackoverfow, I saw someone has said the tag `c++` indicates the latest released version. `type_identity` is available in c++20. I'll tag it later

Comment: I'll report bugs to gcc and clang later

Comment: Not sure that is a correct interpretation of the c++ tag; anyway, I suggest to explicit it ever because, this way, you attract people interested in particular version of the language. And, as explained in c++ tag description, "use a question specific tag for questions related to a specific standard revision"

Comment: liliscent's codes also compile with icc https://godbolt.org/z/QqjeJh

Comment: @陳力: "*I saw someone has said the tag c++ indicates the latest released version*" Even if that's true, C++20 isn't "the latest released version," since it's not finished.